# URLConnection with basic authorization

Tags: java, authorization, urlconnection

Im trying to get all the xml data from a myanimelist request.
I've ried this code (see code below) on an other url and this worked.
Now, for myanimelist you need an account to request queries. I have tried different things like changing the location of `uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", getBasicAuthenticationEncoding());` before and after the `openConnection();` But nothing seems to work. The code below gives me this error: `server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http`.

Can someone help me with this?

**Code: (i used fake pwds for the example)**

```
System.out.println(getXMLFromUrl("https://myanimelist.net/api/anime/search.xml?q=" + "2017"));



private String getBasicAuthenticationEncoding() {
        String username= "username";
        String password = "mypwd";
        String userPassword = username + ":" + password;
        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userPassword.getBytes()));
        return basicAuth;
    }

public String getXMLFromUrl(String url) throws IOException {
         URL u = new URL(url);
         URLConnection uc = u.openConnection();
         uc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", getBasicAuthenticationEncoding());
         InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            br.close();
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

Comment: You are converting between bytes and characters without specifying a charset, so the default charset gets used, which may or may not be correct.  First, change userPassword.getBytes() to `userPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.  Second, use Java’s own [java.util.Base64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) class:  `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`

Comment: I have changed it to: ||String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
       ||but I still get the same error.